# 2x10 drivetrain and chain crossing

Tags: mountain-bike, chain

I've used to ride with 3x10 setup on my MTB. Now I've got a new one with 2x10 (Avalanche 9R Expert).

The question is: do I need to worry less or more about chain crossing on this bike?

This is not a duplicate since I'm mostly interested in difference between 3 and 2*10 setups in terms of chain crossing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cross chaining 18 speed (2 \* 9) bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35002/cross-chaining-18-speed-2-9-bike) and several others on cross chaining. Despite what some say, It does not lead to  "Total protonic reversal", that is caused by crossing the streams, not the chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's less of a problem because you are asking the chain to flex less lateral distance on the 2x10 setup vs the 3x10 setup. On some older 3x drivetrains extreme cross-chaining would not work at all.

I would not run cross chained on a sustained basis. Although it works just fine on most modern 2x setups, it does increase wear on the chain and sprockets. If you need to do it to change down for short steep slopes, or change up for short downhills go ahead, but get on the proper front ring when you can. The ability to change front and rear simultaneously on modern drivetrains helps to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The chain will travel less distance sideways, so less, but still if you are big front, big back, it may still touch the front derailleur. I wouldn't call it something to worry about though.